Drawing of intersecting arrows in java, android studio on constrain layout
I m beginner in programming so, don't be sever in judjing please.
I m  trying to understand how to  realise drawing of intersecting arrows on constrain layout or  other layout , in dependency of a  given  example . On  a  calculator  is given  an  example . My task  is  to draw this logica on appart layout . for  example this one enter image description here I have  an idea how to realise. But  don't  know  how  to  draw a  picture woth intersecting arrows like this one enter image description here.
First task I can  realise with positioned in grid order views on constraint layout.
How can I realise drawing of intersecting arrows between themseves and numbers .
This task is for explicative calculator .`
package com.example.my777;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class pet1 extends View {



    private Paint paint;


    private Path path;




    private Point startPoint;

    private Point endPoint;




    public pet1(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);



        paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(7);



        path = new Path();



        startPoint = new Point(100, 200); // задаем координаты начальной точки (x1, y1)



        endPoint = new Point(100, 400); // задаем координаты конечной точки (x2, y2)





    }



    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);



        path.reset();

        path.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);

        path.lineTo(endPoint.x, endPoint.y);



        double angle = Math.atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x) + Math.toRadians(45);



        path.moveTo(endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

        path.lineTo((float) (endPoint.x + 20 * Math.cos(angle - Math.toRadians(30))),

                (float) (endPoint.y + 20 * Math.sin(angle - Math.toRadians(30))));

        path.moveTo(endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

        path.lineTo((float) (endPoint.x + 20 * Math.cos(angle + Math.toRadians(30))),

                (float) (endPoint.y + 20 * Math.sin(angle + Math.toRadians(30))));



        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }

}
`


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
